# Unable to find my newly added locations in map?

Tags: views, google-maps

I'm unable to find newly added locations in map. Make sure I have enabled below modules:

[image]

->GMAP

->GMAP Location

->Node Locations

->Location CCK

Currently display 14 map points only. But actually I have created 20 locations and can't see all those. Look at below screen shot:

Please advice,
Thanks.

Comment: check out you views setting, have you enable to show all nodes? have you applied any condition or filter?

Comment: Issue is fixed, i have created new content  type then created new view automatically displayed all items in front end.finally deleted old content type and view